# untraceable mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor exceptions in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

some of my android users report a bunch of weird (at least for me) RunnableImplementor exceptions.

Those seems untraceable for me since most of my application code is shared in Xamarin forms, and those exceptions stack traces aren't showing me any useful information regarding how can I solve those bugs.

I would love your help. Relevant images from my Xamarin app centre are attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have three separate issues here. I would think each one of these issues should be separated into it's own question rather than lumping all 3 into one. A simple search on the top-most exception should yield some ideas of where you would start. i.e. `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, `android.os.FileUriExposedException`, and `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException` Stack Overflow has some great existing questions/answers on each of these to which you can figure out what Xamarin.Forms might be doing under the hood with their implementation to things like fragments and dialogs.

Comment: Are your running any background task?

Comment: @JonDouglas Hi, the problem is that I have no valuable data regarding which part of my code causes this exception. The stack trace can't provide anything meaningful.

Comment: @SahilManchanda hmmm... I do run background tasks usually asynchronously .